# How to access style definitions with JavaScript in VueJS SFCs?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass, vue-loader

I am doing an app where I need to extract the CSS inside the style tag in a single file component in Vue JS.

**So I have this basic template:**

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <button class="wrapper__button" @click="sendRequest()" click me></button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sendRequest () {
      console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("STYLE")[0].innerHTML)
      this.$http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/pdf', 'random string').then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style>
.wrapper__button {
  background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
```

Is there a way I can get with Javascript all the data inside the styles in the vue component?

Thanks, guys

Comment: do you mean css styles that you want to grab inside a variable? Or you want to style html from component

Comment: i want to get all the css inside <style></style>

Comment: I'm curious why one needs to extract the `style` tag? The compiled one *(if used `scoped` they will add `[data...]`)*, or which version?? I don't believe this is possible, or even and desired.

Comment: @Xan if my answer solves your bounty, please award the bounty manually, as the original author is seen 11 months ago the last time...

Answer (score 2):

There is, but you need to use [CSS modules](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#css-modules).

Vue Loader's documentation is more detailed about [usage examples](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html#usage):

```
<style module>
.red {
  color: red;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

<template>
  <p :class="$style.red">
    This should be red
  </p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  created () {
    console.log(this.$style.red)
    // -> "red_1VyoJ-uZ"
    // an identifier generated based on filename and className.
  }
}
</script>
```

Vue Loader's documentation also shows [how to use both the Scoped CSS and CSS Modules](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html#opt-in-usage) with this kind of Webpack config:

```js
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  oneOf: [
    // this matches `<style module>`
    {
      resourceQuery: /module/,
      use: [
        'vue-style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: true,
            localIdentName: '[local]_[hash:base64:5]'
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    // this matches plain `<style>` or `<style scoped>`
    {
      use: [
        'vue-style-loader',
        'css-loader'
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, you can do

```
var color = $(".wrapper__button").css("background-color"));
```

to fetch all the css properties. (you will need to do some string manipulation)

```
var color = $(".wrapper__button").attr('style');
```

Here is a working example
https://jsfiddle.net/kLpv30dz/

Comment: i want to get all the css inside <style></style>, not just the background-color

Answer (score 1):

This answer is something different from vue, but you can extract the CSS using Javascript by using `document.styleSheets`

```js
for (var i=0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++){
  var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[i];
  console.log(styleSheet);
}
```

```css
.wrapper{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class=".wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: this seems something i am looking for, but how can i distingue between diferent component styles to get the desired one if i have many component?

Comment: I don't think so beacuse it will give all the stylesheets used on the page, not component wise.